# Accessing coded char set id in IBM MQ

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, ibm-mq

When i read a message from a remote queue manager which has its coded character set id as 819, the sent message has

> CodedCharSetId=1208 , am connecting via 7.x client to a 6x (remote
>   queue)?

How do i get 819 in the export queue instead of 1208, i don't want to hard code in the message

`mqQMgr.CodedCharSetId =819;`

instead i want to access this coded char set id from an attribute/property(so that, it can be dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

If you are using MQ .NET client, then the character set will always be Unicode, 1208 because .NET applications always run in Unicode.

ReadString & ReadLine methods of MQMessage class convert the data in the message to the CharacterSet specified while doing Get whereas WriteString and WriteLine methods convert the given data to the CharacterSet specified during Put.

Comment: Thanks, i would like to set coded character set to 819, so should i just put manager.codedcharacterset=819;I am not sure what this 819 means, 1208 is UTF-8, 473 means ASCII.

Comment: In the get method, this one did the trick,mqMsg.CharacterSet = mqQMgr.CodedCharSetId; it works.

Comment: Shashi - I am having trouble setting up to coded character set id to the target queue manager. How do i set the coded character to match with the queue manager of the target system, in my case the import queue has 437 as codedcharactersetid, the export queue is supposed to have 819, however i get 1200. I don't want to hard code directly rather get the coded character of the target system.